# How is it possible that this series converges?

Tags: calculus, analysis

The divergence of:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{1 \over \sqrt{n(n+1)}}$$
is proved by using the negative form of Cauchy partial sum theorem:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}|S_{2n}-S_{n}|&=&{1\over \sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}+{1\over \sqrt{(n+2)(n+3)}}+\ldots+{1\over \sqrt{2n(2n+1)}}\\&>& {1\over n+2}+{1 \over n+3}+\ldots+{1 \over 2n+1}>{1 \over 4},\end{eqnarray*}$$ therefore the series diverges. What I don't understand is how these inequalities apply.

Can anyone clarify that ?

Comment: $n+1<n+2$, so $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}$ gets smaller when you replace the $n+1$ with $n+2$. The same is true for the other terms. The next inequality you can find in a proof that the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: Observe that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+2)(n+2)}}$ by decreasing the denominator.  This is $\frac{1}{n+2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first inequality is obtained by noting that:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+2)}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+2)(n+2)}}=\frac{1}{n+2}
$$
and analogously for all the other terms.

The second one is obtained by:
$$\frac{1}{n+2}<\frac{1}{2n+1},\;\;\;\;\;\frac{1}{n+3}<\frac{1}{2n+1}
$$
etcetera.

Hence (since $n\geq 1$):
$$\frac{1}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}>\frac{1}{2n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n+1}=\frac{n}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{n}}\geq\frac{1}{3}>\frac{1}{4}
$$

What is basically happening here is comparison with the harmonic series. Maybe in simpler form:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)(n+1)}}=\frac{1}{n+1}$$
Hence (in informal notation):
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n+1}=-1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\;\;\;(=\infty)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$
\frac 1{n+2}+\frac 1{n+3}+\dotsb+\frac 1{n+(n+1)}>\frac 1{2n+1}+\frac 1{2n+1}+\dotsb+\frac 1{2n+1}=\frac{n}{2n+1}\ge\frac13>\frac14
$$
which is stronger than that appeared in the question.

For the other inequality observe that for every $1\le k\le n$ we have
$$
\frac1{\sqrt {(n+k)(n+k+1)}}>\frac1{\sqrt {(n+k+1)(n+k+1)}}=\frac1{n+k+1}
$$
now apply Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

You may also notice that you do not strictly need that set of inequalities.

Since $a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$ is a decreasing sequence, the sum $a_N+a_{N+1}+\ldots+a_{2N-1}$ is greater than $N\cdot a_{2N-1}$, but:
$$ \lim_{N\to +\infty} N\cdot a_{2N-1} = \frac{1}{2},$$
hence the series is not convergent, since its partial sums do not give a Cauchy sequence.